# How to enable price and inventory for custom product type in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I created a custom product type in my WooCommerce application

```
function register_variable_bulk_product_type() {

    class WC_Product_Variable_bulk extends WC_Product_Simple {

        public function __construct($product) {

            $this->product_type = 'variable_bulk';
            parent::__construct($product);
        }

    }

}

add_action('init', 'register_variable_bulk_product_type');

function add_variable_bulk_product($types) {

    $types['variable_bulk'] = __('Variable Bulk');

    return $types;
}

add_filter('product_type_selector', 'add_variable_bulk_product');
```

This shows product type in product data dropdown like as follows,

[image]

**My problem is**

The new product don't have an option for adding inventory and prices, How can I enable these options?

Comment: you want price box in variable bulk product type ?

Comment: Ya,I am trying to manage stock and inventory for this type also

Comment: follow steps from this tutorial http://jeroensormani.com/adding-a-custom-woocommerce-product-type/    It works i had also followed this and it saved my time

Comment: @ShijinTR: did my answer solve your question?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> You need a small JS trick to show Price and Inventory tab, i.e. you
>   need to add class `show_if_{your_custom_product_type}` in your case it
>   will be `show_if_variable_bulk`.

Here is the working code:

```
function wh_variable_bulk_admin_custom_js() {

    if ('product' != get_post_type()) :
        return;
    endif;
    ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            //for Price tab
            jQuery('.product_data_tabs .general_tab').addClass('show_if_variable_bulk').show();
            jQuery('#general_product_data .pricing').addClass('show_if_variable_bulk').show();
            //for Inventory tab
            jQuery('.inventory_options').addClass('show_if_variable_bulk').show();
            jQuery('#inventory_product_data ._manage_stock_field').addClass('show_if_variable_bulk').show();
            jQuery('#inventory_product_data ._sold_individually_field').parent().addClass('show_if_variable_bulk').show();
            jQuery('#inventory_product_data ._sold_individually_field').addClass('show_if_variable_bulk').show();
        });
    </script>
    <?php

}

add_action('admin_footer', 'wh_variable_bulk_admin_custom_js');
```

*Code goes in `functions.php` file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin PHP files.*
**Code is tested and works.**

This is how your general tab will look:

[image]

and this is how inventory tab will look

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: The code is right, i would add a little fix to show the "tax status" fields not appearing under the price fields, to show them you add this: 
    jQuery('._tax_status_field').parent().addClass('show_if_variable_bulk');