# Sold Individually field missing in WooCommerce Custom Product type Inventory tab

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

How can I display "Sold Individually" field in my custom product type "Test Product"?
[image: missing sold individually]

I tried with the following hook function

```
static function addField() {
    echo "<script>jQuery('.show_if_simple').addClass('show_if_test');
    jQuery('._sold_individually_field.show_if_simple').addClass('show_if_test');
    </script>";
    }
    add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data','addField'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add below code in your `function.php` file. you need to add class `show_if_{your_custom_product_type}` in your case it will be `show_if_test`. replace `show_if_simple_rental` with `show_if_{your_custom_product_type}`. for more information [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43109755/how-to-enable-price-and-inventory-for-custom-product-type-in-woocommerce)

```
function wh_simple_rental_admin_custom_js() {

    if ('product' != get_post_type()) :
        return;
    endif;

    ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            //for Inventory tab
            jQuery('.inventory_options').addClass('show_if_simple_rental').show();

            jQuery('#inventory_product_data ._sold_individually_field').parent().addClass('show_if_simple_rental').show();
            jQuery('#inventory_product_data ._sold_individually_field').addClass('show_if_simple_rental').show();
        });
    </script>
    <?php

}

add_action('admin_footer', 'wh_simple_rental_admin_custom_js');
```